# How can i print this 2d array?

Tags: c++

I want to create a 2nd array using a function; the user will enter the dimensions(x,y) and the function will print it; in the first row must appear the numbers 1,2,3...x and in the first column the characters a,b,c,d,e....y(y is given as a number).

For example if the user enters x=5 y=7 it will print:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 
a _ _ _ _ _
b _ _ _ _ _
c _ _ _ _ _
d _ _ _ _ _
f _ _ _ _ _
h _ _ _ _ _
i _ _ _ _ _
```

I wrote some code but I don't know how to do this with the letters.

```
void function(int x,int y)
{ 
    char th[x][y];

    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
    { 
       for (int j = 1; j < y; j++)
       {
          if(i==1 )
          {
            for (int k = 1; k < x; k++)
            {
               th[i][j]=k;
            }
          }
          else if(j==1)
          {
            th[i][j]='a';
          }
          else
          {
            th[i][j]='_';
          }
          std:: cout << th[i][j] <<'\t';
       }

       cout << std::endl;
    }  
 }
```

Comment: May I suggest you fix the indentation of the function, and especially add the missing closing braces?

Comment: What is upper bound of `y`? Probably we overrun alphabet *a-z*. What to do then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the character code representations and the fact that 'b' == 'a' + 1 (and so forth).

If you have a zero-based index I, and you want to convert that to letters, it really is as easy as printing 'a' + I.  If you want it in caps, print 'A' + I.

Also note that you can really simplify those loops.  There's no reason to have three loops nested.  You need a single for loop for the first row (generating the numeric column headers), and then a doubly-nested for-loop for the remaining rows.  Something like the following (completely untested) code:

```
// print header
std::cout << ' ';
for (int i = 0; i != x; ++i)
  std::cout << ' ' << i;
std::cout << '\n';

// print body
for (int j = 0; j != y; ++j)
{
  // column leader
  std::cout << char('a' + j);

  // column body
  for (int i = 0; i != x; ++i)
    std::cout << " _";
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Following up on your desire to have data in cells, you need to allocate space for them.  if you have X columns by Y rows, you need X*Y cells.  You can index these by using X*j+i, where i,j is the column,row you want to access.  Something like:

```
std::vector<int> cells(x * y);

// inside the loop, in place of printing " _", use:
std::cout << ' ' << cells(x * j + i);
```

If you want to keep the underscore for "empty" values, you need to pick some integer to represent a nil value (zero, negative, INT_MAX, whatever) and fill the vector with that.  Then put in an if condition to print the underscore if the cell value is the nil value, and print the cell value directly otherwise.

Comment: thank you.. im working on this and try to fix my code.. when i try to print the letters it prints the ASCII number.. do you know what i have to do?

Comment: this way can i have access to my elements?for example if i want to add a number in the 5 column?

Comment: @nick: Cast the letter to a char type; forgot that, sorry (will update code sample).  If you want to have data in your cells, you'll want to follow Luchian Grigore's advice and dynamically allocate the memory (or use std::vector).

Comment: thanks again for your answer!just to understand better... if i want to edit the element (m,n) i should use this?:"std::cout << ' ' << cells(x * m + n);" i get an error :main.cpp:36: error: no match for call to `(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) (int)'... do you know wthat is this?thanks again

Comment: You need to use the array bracket operator, e.g. cells[x * m + n].

Comment: You'll have to provide more information than that if you want help.

Comment: you are right.. i use this operator..vector  &operator [](int x)
{ return cells[x * m + n];
}  {class Vector
{
...
  double & operator[]( int index );
...
};]

Comment: Your operator should not return a vector, it should return an element of the vector, assuming you want to wrap it at all.  Also, your operator is taking a single int x; not sure what that is supposed to be, but you generally want WIDTH * y + x -- that is, you need to pass in two variables, x and y, so you can't have your own operator[].  Your class should have a function getter for the values, e.g. int get_xy(int x, int y) { return cells[width * y + x]; }, where width is the width of the 2D grid you created.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dynamically allocate the array and release the memory when done:

```
char** th = new char*[x];
for ( int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++ )
   th[i] = new char[y];

//rest of the code

for ( int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++ )
   delete[] th[i];
delete[] th;
```

I must suggest you also look into `std::vector`, it could be better suited for what you're actually doing.

Comment: If he just wants to print it out, there's no reason to allocate anything; or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: But there's no reason to even have that array at all just to print.

Comment: thanks for your answer but im new in c++ and it is a difficult for me to work with allocate memory...although i will try it..thanks again